# Accessing NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo objects very slow above section 200

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a large collection view with hundreds of sections. Accessing the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`' `objects` takes about 3ms for sections 0 to 199.

From section 200 it jumps up from 3ms to about 110ms and remains there for higher sections.

```
extension NSFetchedResultsController
{
    func objectAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) throws -> AnyObject
    {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        guard indexPath.item < section.numberOfObjects else
        {
            throw FetchableError.outOfRange
        }

        guard let sectionObjects = section.objects else // This line 110ms.
        {
            throw FetchableError.outOfRange
        }

        return sectionObjects[indexPath.item] as AnyObject
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` already has a [`object(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller/1622281-object) method, why do you have to implement it yourself?

Comment: Also a table/collection view should never ask for an item with an index path which is not in the current result set of the FRC. Are you trying to work around problems where collection view and FRC are not in sync?

Comment: @MartinR I agree; it's legacy code with 'unknown issue'. At least, using `object(at:)` fixes the delay. But, do you have any idea why accessing sections >= 200 is so slow?

Comment: No, I do not – but I never used collection views with that many sections.